# "wait operation timed out" for sql command in ASP .NET app

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, webforms

I have an old `ASP .NET Web Forms` application. Code-behind - `VB .NET`. It has been working for like 10 years. All was fine and worked very fast.

But yesterday I faced next problem: my `SQL` querys to database began to take much longer time.

I had next code in `.aspx` file:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand=" "SOME SELECT DB QUERY (hardcoded)" "> 
    <!-- I know, that it is bad way to configure select command. But I'm not an author -->
     <SelectParameters>
        <!-- Parameters -->
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This `SQL` query take like < `0.1` sec to be processed with every parameter (tested) on server in MS SQL management studio. Thats fine.

But my application started to take timeout error. In SQL server profiler this querys (hardcoded) was taking for > `30` sec's (timeout) (with some parameters It worked for like 14 - 20 sec's. But it is still much more longer, that was for like 2 days ago).

**Important**: I have solved this issue. I have maked stored procedure in my MS SQL database with this select query.

And changed `.aspx` code to this one:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand=" "PROCEDURENAME" " SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <!-- Parameters -->
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And that solved my issue.

**Question** is: Why has it solved my issue? I can't really understand this. And it's very interesting for me.

[Full error code](https://gist.github.com/Pulichev/10ec95efa4799e64f310b4f72cdca198)

Comment: It probably is an issue with the query and indexing.  I would guess that the table has now grown to the point where the execution simply takes too long.  Can you provide details on the query?

Comment: @JohnPasquet this query execute time in ms sql management studio for like 0.1 sec. Or I haven't understood you correctly?

Comment: Canonical reading: [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html)

Comment: Something else may be that it could be returning too much data.  Is that a possibility? Moxet Bbit?

Comment: @JohnPasquet it returning like 260 rows

Comment: @AlexK.Thank you. I will check. Hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your DB connect query might be taking more time to execute, or server is taking more time to execute DB query, You can check the server where DB is hosted.
Check if there are too many application pools running for IIS.

You can also increase CommandTimeout for your connection from the config file.

Comment: Increasing time out is not the solution. I haven't change anything for like last month. But the problem appeared. Anyway thx for your answer

Comment: Server response time also affects connection time out if the server is taking too much time to respond. There are possibilities that server is slow. If you use your hard coded DB query still you get wait timeout.

Comment: I can't realy imagine, that it can be the problem. It was working for < 1 sec 2 days ago. And now it can work for 30 secs? This db working for 10 years atleast. Server with IIS working fine I think (it has more than enough memory, CPU etc). I haven't change something for a long period of time

Comment: And sometimes it works, when query returns 260 rows, and works fast, and doesn't work with 250. Idk. I have no idea. I will start with reading the Alex K. suggested article. Anyway thanks